# Hamiltonian for a 1D spin chain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, hamiltonian, spin-chains

I am trying to implement the Lanczos algorithm to tridiagonalize the Hamiltonian for a 1D spin chain of length $L$, but I am unable to decipher from my professor's notes (here's a [link](https://imgur.com/a/wg5jmwv)), what the action the Hamiltonian has on a random vector (or for that matter what the Hamiltonian is). My touble arises at Eqn. 20 in these notes. They say that the Hamiltonian is $$\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}P_{ij}-\frac{L}{2}I\bigg).$$ However, this is really confusing to me since if $P_{ij}$ is what he defined in Eqn. 18, then the resulting matrix is just a 4 by 4 matrix and not $2^L\times 2^L$ as he claims it should be. If it's not the case that $P_{ij}$ is the same as in Eqn. 18, then what is it, and how do I compute this Hamiltonian (or at the very least) the Hamiltonian's action on a vector, $v$?

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly each of those summands is $I^{\otimes (i-1)} \otimes P_{ij} \otimes I^{\otimes k}$ so that each summand acts as the identity on all but two of the spins so maybe $P_{ij}$ is only 4 by 4 but this extension with the identity operators is actually $2^L$ by $2^L$. I put $k$ here just to say the rest it is something like $L-i$ but I may be off by 1 or 2 and didn't check which.